# Why CPython pre-allocates some integer numbers?

Tags: python, performance, caching, allocation, cpython

From the CPython documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong), is stated that:

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

Which makes this comparison true:

```
>>> a = -3
>>> b = -3
>>> a is b
True
```

I'm wondering what is the reason behind this, why are some numbers pre-allocated and why those numbers in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the implementors of CPython have decided that that's a good range to have preallocated for perfomance reasons, as it covers the most commonly used integer values. There's nothing magical about the range `[-5,256]`. The few negative numbers are probably included in the range for common error codes and negative indexing of lists, and the upper limit was just set to a nice, round power of two.

A comment from the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/918403cfc3304d27e80fb792357f40bb3ba69c4e/Objects/longobject.c#L37-L43):

> ```
> /* Small integers are preallocated in this array so that they
>    can be shared.
>    The integers that are preallocated are those in the range
>    -NSMALLNEGINTS (inclusive) to NSMALLPOSINTS (not inclusive).
> */
> ```